# Angular2 how to do Minification and Compression of js files and reduce the bundle and file size for production

Tags: angular, deployment, production

When i generate the production build for angular2 app my main.bundle.js and vendor.bundle.js ranges the file size to 15MB(main.bundle.js) and 40MB(vendor.bundle.js). On start up of app it takes time to load the these js files. Also performing the build for production using **aot** and **build-optimizer** also does not make difference in the file size the file size is reduced to 2MB (main.bundle.js) and 8MB for (vendor.bundle.js)

Does any one know how to achieve minification and compression of javascript files and improve the performance of the app. I have also gone through the tree-shaking production process for rollup javascript size but dint get the idea what is need to be done and how ?? Does any one know how to achieve this would be a great help and would save my time.Thanks in advance

Comment: which version of angular you are using?

Comment: My Angular version is v.4

Comment: you can use `cli` to do that for you

Comment: you've got 40mg lines of code ? you definitely need to seperate them into modules and lazy load tghem

Comment: @Aravind: how using cli i dint get exactly..?

Comment: `ng build --prod`

Comment: This command does not optimize the file sizes......